# Paypal button not working on mobile website

Tags: mobile, paypal, standards, payment

I am using Paypal to accept payments on a website. Its working fine on the full size website but when I implement the same code on the mobile version of the website which runs jQuery mobile, the 'add to cart' button doesn't work.

I'm using website payments standard so its not as simple as adding "-mobile" as with the express checkout in this post: [Paypal Checkout in mobile website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893457/paypal-checkout-in-mobile-website)

Paypal says the page should automatically re-direct but it doesn't.

My button is also not showing correctly which is rather strange. On my laptop (on mobile website) the button is stretched strangely, and on my phone (on mobile website) the button looks strange aswell.

Here is my code for the Paypal button:

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="ZQK9WXTYG3SDN">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Weekend Ticket Type">Weekend Ticket Type</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
<option value="Full Price Weekend Ticket">Full Price Weekend Ticket £42.00 GBP</option>
<option value="Weekend Concession Ticket">Weekend Concession Ticket £40.00 GBP</option>
<option value="Under 12 Weekend Ticket">Under 12 Weekend Ticket £0.00 GBP</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input style="padding:20px 0px 0px 0px;" width="120" type="image" src="http://www.website-domain.com/images/PayPal-button.jpg" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

(I have changed the website domain name to stop it getting picked up in search engines ;-)

Many thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest jQuery Mobile is hijacking your form submit (like it does with `<a href="..">` tags too).
Try adding `data-ajax="false"`to your `<form>` tag.

You can find out more about this behaviour here:
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/forms-sample.html

Or globally disable it by adding this snippet to your code:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
```